# $L= \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt 2, \sqrt 3)$ is normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

$L= \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt 2, \sqrt 3)$ is normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ or not?

I noted that $L= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)$ using tower law.
$[L:\mathbb{Q}]=4\ne 2$ so can't conclude from 'quadratic extensions are normal'.
Suppose that the extension is normal. Then Irr($\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)=p(x)$ must split in $L$.
$p(x)=(x^2-2)^2-24$. So L must contain splitting field of $p$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is just $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)$. But this does not give me a contradiction.

So it seems that the extension is normal. To prove this: Take $a\in L$. Consider $q(x)= Irr (a, \mathbb{Q})$. It must be shown that $q$ splits in $L$. But I am not sure how to show this.

---

**Edit:** (added by Kenny, see comments).

The OP is using this definition for a normal extension.

> An algebraic extension $K/F$ is normal iff for every $k$ in $K$, $irr (k, F)$ splits in $K$.

This is equivalent to the following:

> For every irreducible polynomial $p(x)$ in $F[x]$ with a root in $K$, $p(x)$ splits in $K$.

At the present moment, this is the only definition the OP is aware of. The OP is specifically looking for an argument that starts from this definition.

Comment: Do you know that there is another way to characterise normal extensions: $L$ is a normal extension of $F$ iff $L$ is the splitting field of some polynomial in $F[X]$.

Comment: **Hint :** It is the splitting field of $(X^2-2)(X^2-3)$.

Comment: @KennyWong No, I don't know that. I use the following definition: An algebraic extension K/F is normal iff for every k in K, irr (k, F) splits in K. I know that this is equivalent to the following: For every irreducible polynomial p(x) in F[x] with a root in K, p(x) splits in K.

Comment: How do I prove normality using the definition I'm using?

Comment: Quite honestly, I would first prove that my definitions implies your definition. And then I would prove that your field extension is normal, by my definition.

Comment: @KennyWong: Normality has so many definitions (equivalent):-). How do you prove equivalence of the two definitions? Thanks.

Comment: @Koro I took the liberty of editing your question to include this context.

Comment: @KennyWong: thank you!

Comment: @KennyWong: The definition you mentioned is true for all normal extensions or only for finite normal extensions?

Comment: Finite extensions, I think. Sorry!

Comment: @KennyWong: I found this definition (valid for finite extensions) in a book. The book shows the equivalence for finite normal extensions.

Comment: @Koro Ah, I see you've found the equivalence already... That's cool. For what it's worth, I wrote an answer, but you're probably already sorted. :)

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the comments, there are several equivalent definitions of what it means for a finite field extension $L : F$ to be normal.

> **Definition 1.** The field extension $L : F$ is normal iff $L$ is the splitting field for some polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$

> **Definition 2.** The field extension $L : F$ is normal iff every irreducible polynomial $p(x) \in F[x]$ with at least one root in $L$ splits completely in $L$.

As I understand it, you are familiar only with Definition 2.

However, the problem is much easier to solve if we work with Definition 1. Indeed, as @TheSilverDoe points out, your $L$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $(x^2 - 2)(x^2 - 3) \in \mathbb Q[x]$.

---

So how do we prove that Definition 1 implies Definition 2?

Let's suppose that $L$ is the splitting field of some $f(x) \in F[x]$. Let $p(x) \in F[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial with a root $a \in L$. We want to prove that $p(x)$ splits completely over $L$.

I think the cleanest approach is to start by constructing a field $K$ such that (i) $L \subset K$ and (ii) $p(x)$ splits completely in $K$. (For example, we could take $K$ to be the splitting field of $p(x)$ over $L$.)

Let $b$ be some root of $p(x)$ in $K$. Our goal is to prove that $b$ is in fact in $L$.

At this point, we should draw a diagram, showing various important subfields of $K$ and the relationships between them.

[image: tower]

Now we can make a few observations.

**Observation 1:** $[F(a) : F] = [F(b) : F]$.

To see this, note that $a$ and $b$ are both roots of the irreducible polynomial $p(x) \in F[x]$.

Therefore, there exists an isomorphism $g : F(a) \to F(b)$ that sends $a \mapsto b$ and fixes elements of $F$.

The claim that $[F(a) : F] = [F(b) : F]$ follows.

**Observation 2:** $[L(a) : F(a)] = [L(b) : F(b)]$.

To see this, observe that $L(a)$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F(a)$, and $L(b)$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F(b)$.

The isomorphism $g : F(a) \to F(b)$ induces an isomorphism $\hat g : F(a)[x] \to F(b)[x]$. Since $g$ fixes elements of $F$, and the polynomial $f$ has all of its coefficients in $F$, we have that $\hat g(f) = f$. Thus:

- $g: F(a) \to F(b)$ is an isomorphism.
- $L(a)$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $F(a)$.
- $L(b)$ is the splitting field of $\hat g(f)$ over $F(b)$.

Therefore, by the uniqueness theorem for splitting fields, $g$ extends to an isomorphism $\widetilde g : L(a) \to L(b)$. The claim that $[L(a) : F(a)] = [L(b) : F(b)]$ follows immediately.

**Observation 3:** $[L(a) : L] = 1$.

This is trivial, since $a$ is in $L$ by assumption.

Anyway, using our three observations together with the tower law, we can see that
\begin{multline} [L(b) : L] = \frac{[L(b) : F]}{[L:F]} = \frac{[L(b) : F(b)] [F(b) : F]}{[L:F]} \\ = \frac{[L(a) : F(a)] [F(a) : F]}{[L:F]} = \frac{[L(a) : F]}{[L:F]} = [L(a) : L] = 1.\end{multline}

This proves that $b$ is in $L$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct way, using your definition only.

Let $\alpha\in L$, and let $f=Irr(\alpha,\mathbb{Q})$.

Write $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}$, where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Set $g=(X-(a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}))(X-(a-b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}-d\sqrt{6}))(X-(a+b\sqrt{2}-c\sqrt{3}-d\sqrt{6}))(X-(a-b\sqrt{2}-c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}))$.

Expanding everything, one may see that $g\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Since $g(\alpha)=0$, $f\mid g$. But $g$ splits in $L$, and thus so does $f$. QED.